# Template parameter difference between Collectors.toList and Stream.toList

Tags: java, java-16

Found a difference between collect(Collectors.toList()) and Stream.toList().  See

```
class Animal { }
class Cat extends Animal { }
record House(Cat cat) { }

class Stuff {
    public static void function() {
        List<House> houses = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Animal> animals1 = 
            houses.stream()
                  .map(House::cat)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList()); // ok
        List<Animal> animals2 =
            houses.stream()
                  .map(House::cat).toList(); // compile error
        List<Animal> animals3 =
            houses.stream()
                  .map(House::cat)
                  .map(cat -> (Animal) cat).toList(); // ok
    }
}
```

The collect(Collectors.toList()) is able to give me a List of Animal or List of Cat.  But the Stream.toList() can only give a List of Cat.

The question is there any way to make Stream.toList() work.  In my real world example I have a class which overrides shutdownNow, which returns a list of Runnable, so my class was calling something.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()), but something.stream().toList() returns a list of MyRunnable.

A part of me wishes they declared the function as `default <U super T> List<U> toList()` instead of `default List<T> toList()`, though strangely that is a compile error on my machine (my compiler seems to be ok with U extends T, not U super T).

Comment: You seem to know why `toList` doesn't compile, because of the generic nature of its signature. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Post edited to be a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a simple answer here.

Start with

```
var stream = houses.stream().map(House::cat)
```

Here, `stream` has type `Stream<Cat>`.  The `Stream::toList` method gives you a list of the stream element type, which here is `Cat`.  So `stream.toList()` is of type `List<Cat>`.  There's no choice here.

`Collector` has multiple type variables, including the type of the input element, and the type of the output result.  There is a lot of flexibility to create a `Collector` that takes in `Cat` and produces `List<Cat>`, `List<Animal>`, `Set<Animal>`, etc.  This flexibility is partially hidden by the genericity of `Stream::collect` (and also the generic method `Collectors::toList`); inferring the generic type parameters for this method can take into account the desired result type on the LHS.  So the language papers over the gap between `Cat` and `Animal` for you, because there's another level of indirection between the stream and the result.

As @Eugene pointed out, you could get a more general type out:

```
List<? extends Animal> animals2 = houses.stream().map(House::cat).toList()
```

This has nothing to do with streams; it is just because `List<? extends Animal>` is a supertype of `List<Cat>`.  But there's an easier way.  If you want a `List<Animal>`, and you want to use `toList()`, change the stream type to a `Stream<Animal>`:

```
List<Animal> animals = houses.stream().map(h -> (Animal) h.cat()).toList()
```

`Stream::map` is also generic, so by having the RHS of the lambda be `Animal`, not `Cat`, you get a `Stream<Animal>` out, and then `toList()` gives you a `List<Animal>`.

You could also break it up, if you like that better:

```
List<Animal> animals = houses.stream().map(House::cat)
                                      .map(c -> (Animal) c).toList()
```

What is tripping you up is that, because `collect` is a generic method (and so `Collectors::toList`), there is additional flexibility to infer a slightly different type, whereas in the simpler stream, everything is more explicit, so if you want to adjust the types, you have to do that in imperative code.

Comment: Another trick is to use Type Witness, `List<Animal> animals = houses.stream().<Animal>map(House::cat).toList()`

Answer (score 3):

That is impossible to achieve.

`Collectors::toList` has a declaration of `? extends T`. On the other hand `Stream::toList` returns a `List<T>`, you are stuck.

You can workaround that (partially), via:

```
List<? extends Animal> animals2 = houses.stream().map(House::cat).toList();
```

What you are thinking is `U super T`, but that is not supported, unfortunately. People occasionally found good real use cases for it - but support is not there.